# Change Javascript timer with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create the following result[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tKcq.png)

It is a cowntdown that I want to be in my html code.I have created the timer with javascript and it works fine but I cannot make it appear as I want in my html.I want it to appear exactly like the picture.

Here is my code

my html

```
<div class="container">
    <hr class="new4">
        <p class="countdown text-center">Μέχρι το δορυφορικό συμπόσιο απομένουν</p>
        <p id="timer" class="timer text-center"></p> 
        
        
        <hr class="new4">
        
    </div>
```

and my javascript

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 19, 2020 16:30:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + " " + hours + " "
  + minutes + " " + seconds + " ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Συμβαίνει Τώρα";
  }
}, 1000);
```

and my css

```
hr.new4 {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.timer{
    font-size: 117px;
    color:white;
}
```

Here is how it looks for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us34s.png)

I can not understand how to make the text apear exatly bellow the numbers and I cant understand how to add paddings between each of the elements that get return by the javascript document.getElementById() function.
Please help me it is an emerjency I must have it until tomorow

Comment: Note that parsing dates in any format other than certain variants of ISO 8601 are not guaranteed to work across browsers. Either reformat your date to use YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss format or use numbers as arguments. See [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/215552)

Answer (score 0):

To make each time unit a different element, update the timer HTML like so:

```js
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = `
  <span data-unit="Days">${days}</span>
  <span data-unit="Hours">${hours}</span>
  <span data-unit="Minutes">${minutes}</span>
  <span data-unit="Seconds">${seconds}</span>
`;
```

Then style them using CSS, to add margin, and a pseudo element representing the unit:

```css
#timer span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

#timer span:before {
  content: attr(data-unit);
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(offsetX, offsetY); /* Here you have to find the correct X and Y values */
}
```

Comment: hi can you tell me how to center the text unde the numbers? transform moves all the text, i want each text to be centered

Comment: @Stefanie well for that you’ll have to try out different translate values, and you can apply specific ones for the different units using `:nth-child()`. But it seems like @Steve Cruz has a good solution too, you should check it out

Answer (score 0):

To properly center the text under the numbers I recommend that you use flexbox.

I created additional containers to properly space things with `display: flex` and used `flex-direction: column` when necessary or did not defining any value for my flex container in some places because the default value for `flex-direction` is `row`.

Note that I separated the timer into different `<p>` and used static values in our `<p>` elements for our digits that represent days, hours, minutes and seconds:

- Separating them into different `<p>` allow us to have more control over their positioning.
- The static values are only for illustrative purposes because I did not modify your JavaScript code.
- You have to modify your JavaScript code to update each `<p>` in the HTML individually.

Check my CodePen example with the modified HTML and CSS: https://codepen.io/stevescruz/pen/bGpLjKj.

```html
<div class="container">
    <hr class="new4">
    <div class="timer-container">
        <p class="countdown text-center">Μέχρι το δορυφορικό συμπόσιο απομένουν</p>
        <div class="content-container">
            <div class="unit-container">
                <p id="timer" class="timer text-center">22</p>
                <p class="timer-text">day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="unit-container">
                <p id="timer" class="timer text-center">23</p>
                <p class="timer-text">hours</p>
            </div>
            <div class="unit-container">
                <p id="timer" class="timer text-center">41</p>
                <p class="timer-text">min</p>
            </div>
            <div class="unit-container">
                <p id="timer" class="timer text-center">16</p>
                <p class="timer-text">sec</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="new4">
</div>
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

hr.new4 {
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.timer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.countdown {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;

    align-self: center;
}

.unit-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.timer {
    font-size: 117px;
    color: white;
}

.timer-text {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
}

body {
    background: #194079;
}
```